# Scanf and printf functions in assembly, example on char* and double

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att

I have a task to do, call the scanf and printf functions using the char* and double variables. Char* is working, but I have problem with double.

Function: is for scanf/printf char*, function1: is for scanf/printf double. For example, my results after compilation:

(scanf)b

(printf)char: b

(scanf)1.3

(printf)double:
99997200381866062965879955188785948733402760577162787362451212786.000000

It appears the problem is with printf for double variable but I have no idea how to solve it.

```
.data
STDIN = 0
STDOUT = 1
SYSREAD = 3
SYSWRITE = 4
SYSEXIT = 1
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0

format_inchar: .string "%c"
format_indouble: .string "%lf"
char: .ascii " "
double: .double 0.0

format_string1: .string "char: %c\n"   
format_double1: .string "double: %f\n"
.text
.global main
main:

function:

    push $char
    push $format_inchar
    call scanf

    push char
    push $format_string1
    call printf

function1:

    push $double
    push $format_indouble
    call scanf

    push double
    push $format_double1
    call printf

exit:
movl $SYSEXIT, %eax
movl $EXIT_SUCCESS, %ebx
int $0x80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32-bit code can't `push` a 64-bit `double` from memory with one instruction.  64-bit code doesn't pass args on the stack, so I assume this is intended to be 32-bit code.  (Also from using `int 0x80`.)

**`push double` in 32-bit code is `pushl` that pushes the low 4 bytes**.  `printf` was taking the high 4 bytes (containing the exponent and most-significant bits of the mantissa) from whatever was above it on the stack.  In that case, assuming `scanf` didn't clobber its stack args, the high 4 bytes of your `double` bit-pattern came from the address `$format_indouble`.

**You probably want `pushl double+4` ; `pushl double` to push the 8-byte `double` in 2 halves.**

(The operand-size suffix is optional here, but I'd recommend it to avoid the ambiguity that got you.)

Or you could use SSE2 `movsd` to copy 8 bytes to the stack.

```
    sub    $8, %esp
    movsd  double, %xmm0
    movsd  %xmm0, (%esp)
```

(`push` is special and can copy from memory to memory.  Instructions with explicit source and destination can't do that.)

Of course you don't need static storage space for your inputs; you could pass pointers to stack memory to `scanf`.  Then your `double` would be on the stack already, and you could just store a pointer to a format string below it.

---

BTW, you don't have the stack aligned by 16 when you call `scanf` and `printf`.  The ABI does require this, so you got lucky that your build of glibc happens not to use `movaps` on stack memory in these functions, which would segfault.

Before `main` is called, the stack is aligned by 16.  That `call` pushes a return address.  So 3 more pushes re-aligns that stack.  One dummy push on function entry will set you up for functions with 8 bytes of args.

Also normally you'd `add $8, %esp` after a call returns to clear the args from the stack.

---

**Variable names:** `double` is a type name (and keyword) in C.  That makes it a weird name for an assembly program that calls C functions.  Something like `dbl` might look better.

Comment: You nailed it (quel surprise) , but it is worth a reminder that the ABI is defined by architecture + platform.   You describe the sysv/386 abi; but some winDOwS variants might be different.

Comment: @mevets: With Windows `fastcall` the OP's `char` version wouldn't have worked either.  Except Windows doesn't use 32-bit `fastcall` for variadic functions because it's a callee-pops convention; IIRC i386 Windows printf/scanf use the cdecl calling convention, which matches i386 System V in this case.